# Rendering an OpenGL texture where each pixel represents a fix area at a given distance from the camera

Tags: c++, opengl, glu

I wish to size an OpenGL texture so that at the maximum clipping distance each pixel will represent a fixed area, say 0.25 m<sup>2</sup>, i.e. each pixel represents a square of 0.5m by 0.5m.

For example.

```cpp
GLint TextureWidth = GLint(HorizViewAngle*pi*RangeDistance / 180.0 / ResolutionAtDistance);
GLint TextureHeight = GLint(VertViewAngle*pi*RangeDistance / 180.0 / ResolutionAtDistance);
```

`HorizViewAngle` will be typically 120 degrees, with a  `VertViewAngle` of 60, which is based around a humans field of view.
Furthermore, `RangeDistance` value will be 100 and `ResolutionAtDistance` = 0.5

The above code is base on the formula of an Arc = θ × (π/180) × r.

For setting the clipping distance I am using OpenGL Utility Library (GLU) gluPerspective

```cpp
GLdouble AspectRatio = HorizViewAngle / VertViewAngle ;
gluPerspective(VertViewAngle, AspectRatio, 0.01, RangeDistance);
```

I was wondering if anyone else has had experience of doing this in OpenGL and what issues I should be looking out for. Such as image distortion which could impact the projected image. For example, I believe if I was to extend the field of view to 180 degrees, then it would be better to render two 90 degree textures and stitch them together.

Comment: "*at the maximum clipping distance each pixel will represent a fixed area*" That doesn't make sense. The distance that a texel in a texture represents depends on the following: 1) the mapping of the texture onto a polygon, 2) the coordinates of the polygon in the space in question, and 3) the size of the texture. If you have a quad that is 256x256 meters in size (in world space), and you map a 512x512 texture onto it such that covers that entire quad, then the coverage of each texel will be a half-meter square. This has nothing to do with the "maximum clipping distance".

Comment: To put it more simply, changing your perspective on the world does not change the *world*.

Comment: Beware that the way perspective projection works in GL makes surfaces of "equal" distance flat, not spherical. The texture size probably needs to be proportional to a `tan(fov/2)`, not `fov`.

Comment: Another way to think of is, is if you were representing say a emergency exit sign, what resolution would you required to make the image representative of what a person would see at a 100 metres away.

Comment: @PeterLawrence: "*what resolution would you required to make the image representative of what a person would see at a 100 metres away.*" There isn't one, because human eyes don't have a fixed resolution. You can ask what resolution would give the texture a particular clarity at a certain rendering resolution, but that has little to do with human vision.

Comment: @NicolBolas correct, it for testing various image reignition method and correlating with human cognition (seeing, recognising and acting on information). So if you have an object at X metres away and render that object at different resolutions, the question is when will that object become recognisable. Hence I need to equate distance with pixel size and compared with research on human cognition. If you want to know more google "signage visibility catchment area"